# How can I get the numeric value of metric in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

How can I get the numeric value of a metric in SonarQube?

For example: **<%= format_measure('ncloc') -%>** will display the number of lines of code.

But I need to get the value (number of lines) in some variable to process further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got this,<%  numberOfbugs = @snapshot.measure(numberOfbugs) %>   
    Number of bugs: <%=  numberOfbugs.value %> <br>

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you developing a UI plugin? what is your need? what version of SQ are you targeting?

Comment: Working on a plugin, need to show custom metric value in widget. Currently working on 5.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Dashboards are [dropped](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-399) in SonarQube 6.1. I suggest to not put too much effort on writing widgets.

Moreover, Ruby code is being dropped and we don't know yet how it will be replaced or if it will be. I've notified our documentation team to make things clearer.

Regarding your question, you can assign the result of `format_measure(…)` to a variable and do whatever you want in Ruby.

Comment: I was dong like this ...,<% numberOfbugs = @snapshot.measure(numberOfbugs) %> Number of bugs: <%= numberOfbugs.value %>